# Compact way using generators/"with ... as" in Python

Tags: python, generator, with-statement

I have the following data structure:

```
var = [['x_A_B', 1], ['x_A_C', 1], ['x_B_A', 1], ['x_B_D', 1], ['x_C_A', 1], ['x_C_D', 1], ['x_D_B', 1], ['x_D_C', 1]]
```

I would like to extract these values as

```
var2 = [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')]
```

Currently I use the following line

```
var2 = [(item[0].split("_")[1], item[0].split("_")[2]) for item in var]
```

but it's tedious to write, and also calculates the same `split` two times.
Is there a way of writing this in a compact way, maybe with keywords `with ... as`, something like this?

```
# not working
var2 = [(u, v) with item[0].split("_") as _, u, v for item in var]
```

EDIT: I was looking for a more general solution, where I can use arbitrary indices of the split string with arbitrary length of substrings, I just used an improper example. See the solution I accepted.

Comment: `item[0].split("_")[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question with a similar approach to your example, and including your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362449/compact-way-using-generators-with-as-in-python/49362594#comment85725268_49362594):

> Yes that works in this case, @internet_user also suggested this. But
>   what if the indices I need are not consecutive, i.e. I need 0 and 2?

The `with...as...` syntax is for context managers, which has a totally different use. However, a work-around is to use for-loop unpacking.

```
var = [['x_A_B', 1], ['x_A_C', 1], ['x_B_A', 1], ['x_B_D', 1], ['x_C_A', 1], ['x_C_D', 1], ['x_D_B', 1], ['x_D_C', 1]]

var2 = [(u, v) for item in var for _, u, v in (item[0].split("_"), )]

print(var2)
```

Comment: I was looking for exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

The general case would be:

```
[tuple(item[0].split('_')[1:3]) for item in var]
```

And the most general case would be:

```
indices = {1,2}
[tuple([x for i, x in enumerate(item[0].split('_')) if i in indices]) for item in var]
```

But if you have two indices that are one next to another this would be too much.

Comment: Yes that works in this case, @internet_user also suggested this. But what if the indices I need are not consecutive, i.e. I need 0 and 2?

Comment: @Rolf you keep changing the question and quite frankly it starts to get annoying.

Comment: @timgeb Sorry for that, I just stumble upon this problem multiple times, and I was interested in a very general solution. But I admit the current example I gave is an easier one.

Answer (score 2):

Why even use `split`? You know the exact indices of the letters you want.

```
>>> var = [['x_A_B', 1], ['x_A_C', 1], ['x_B_A', 1], ['x_B_D', 1], ['x_C_A', 1], ['x_C_D', 1], ['x_D_B', 1], ['x_D_C', 1]]
>>> [(x[0][2], x[0][4]) for x in var]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')]
```

> I am interested in a more general case, suppose there can be 'x_word1_word2' variable names.

Well in that case internet_user gave you the solution in the comments.

```
>>> var = [['x_A_B', 1], ['x_word1_word2']]
>>> [tuple(x[0].rsplit('_', 2)[1:]) for x in var]
[('A', 'B'), ('word1', 'word2')]
```

(I used `rsplit` constrained to two splits for a very minor efficiency improvement.)

Comment: I am interested in a more general case, suppose there can be `x_word1_word2` variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already talk about your specific case. In the more general case, if you're observing that the same value appears multiple times in a comprehension...

```
var2 = [(item[0].split("_")[1], item[0].split("_")[2]) for item in var]
        ^                       ^
```

and you'd like to avoid this repetition. Is that about right?

One way is to use a nested loop, but that's really a code golfing trick...

```
[(parts[1], parts[2] for item in var for parts in [item[0].split("_")]]
# or 
[(a, b) for item in var for (_, a, b) in [item[0].split("_")]]
```

but yeah, that wouldn't pass code review...

How about writing a function instead?

```
def extract_parts(item):
    parts = item[0].split("_")
    return parts[1], parts[2]

[extract_parts(item) for item in var]
# or:
map(extract_parts, var)
```

Comment: I was looking for a one-line solution. The two versions you wrote are okay, but the answer I accepted by abccd is a bit clearer. At least it's the closest of how my brain works.

Comment: Sure. I personally find the one-liner version a bit too clever for its own good and I'd rather extract a helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[tuple(x[0].split('_')[1:]) for x in var]

out: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')]
```